# Is react native consumes more battery power?

Tags: react-native

My RN application is consuming more battery power of android and iOS devices. Can any one let me know why it is consuming more batter in comparison to native application?

Comment: You need to explain what you are comparing to. Impossible to help you if your just asking for a single app and why it is drawing a certain amount of memory.

Comment: What does your RN application do?

Comment: No, its not related to only one applications I have seen this almost all applications in my organisations those are actually created using RN and they have more battery consumptions at all.

Comment: My application just have User login, signup, some game static data api calling and showing list in app only. As I know, RN does not provide multithreading for Android bridging methods but in iOS it do. Perhaps it is the cause to consuming battery power more.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered high battery consumption when I scrolled my infinite list made using default FlatList. It needed a lot of computations of layout so it loaded up CPU and that caused the battery go empty. I solved it by using recycler list view and preconfigured layout. In fact, every JS app will kick the battery harder than native